# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания вокруг слова "отнюдь"?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлена пунктуация вокруг слова отнюдь?

> Слово «реал» (re all – повтор всего) тоже говорит, что на самом деле нас окружает иллюзия.
> Но все думают, что это действительность – **отнюдь**, это иллюзия: действительность находится
> субстанциальном мире.

Comment: Пунктуация — раздел науки о языке: о знаках препинания и правилах постановки этих знаков. Кто же её расставляет? Она же наука...

Comment: @shampar 2) *разг.* Знаки препинания. Но да, "расставить пунктуацию" стилистически неверно. Дело в том, что она существует только после расстановки. Это применённые знаки препинания. А "расставлена пунктуация" подразумевает, что была некая пунктуация и её расставили.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написала так: *Все думают, **что это действительность – отнюдь,** это иллюзия: действительность находится в субстанциальном мире.*

(1) Можно сравнить: *Все думают, что это действительность – **но нет**, это иллюзия: действительность находится в субстанциальном мире.*

Противопоставление во второй части, поэтому **первый союз НО** не нужен.

(2) Зарывающая запятая после придаточного здесь не нужна, вместо нее **тире**.

Сравнить: *Все думают, что это действительность, **но нет**, это иллюзия: действительность находится в субстанциальном мире.* Здесь стоит запятая, но ее нужно заменить **тире** (обозначение увеличенной паузы).

[О частице ***отнюдь***](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/487/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%B4%D1%8C)

Частица (в ответной реплике). То же, что «нет». Обособляется или оформляется как отдельное предложение. «Вы не замерзли?» – «Отнюдь, в доме очень тепло». «Ты с этим согласен?» – «Отнюдь».

Comment: "Но нет" и "нет" ("отнюдь") существенно отличаются в плане интонации. У "но нет" выше примыкание за счёт союза.

Comment: Я думаю, что интонация не изменилась при замене.

Comment: "Но" связывает. Необходимость тире союзом нивелируется.

Comment: Кстати, из-за этого единый знак уже не подходит.

Comment: Я предложила вариант, который считаю правильным.  Пожалуйста, не пишите критику, но запишите свой вариант редактирования в поле ответа.

Comment: Да это не критика. Ну хватит уже трястись. Просто информация для вас. Цените.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 1):

> Правильно ли расставлена пунктуация вокруг слова отнюдь?

**Правильно.** Хотя наверное, не совсем правильно: перед тире стоило бы поставить запятую, закрывающую придаточное, или заменить сочетание запятой и тире на точку с запятой.

Обычно «[**отнюдь**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_516)» употребляется в сочетании с частицей «не» и не обособляется.

Но в приведённом в вопросе предложении «отнюдь» **должно быть обособлено**. Здесь оно выступает **в качестве отдельной самостоятельной реплики**, равной по значению предложениям «отнюдь нет», «вовсе нет».

**Из «Нового объяснительного словаря синонимов русского языка» под ред. Ю. Апресяна:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну у вас и источников. Почти на всё найдётся. А чего вы удалили предыдущий аккаунт?

Comment: ..……………..………….

Comment: Ничего не понял. У меня квадратик вместо символа.

Comment: А может, вопрос из-за желания узнать, нужна ли запятая перед тире?

Comment: Не думаю, здесь не тот случай, когда надо закрыть придаточное. Но единый знак и его интонация подходят, судя по примерам Розенталя. После "хотя" нужна запятая, частицы к вводным не примыкают.

Comment: Если точка с запятой, то не будет противопоставления частей. Не логично.

Comment: Согласен. Лучше поставить запятую после придаточного и точку после отнюдь,